# Large enough bracket size

Tags: brackets

```
$$\Sh(E/K)=\ker\textbraceleft WC(E/K)\rightarrow\prod_{\nu\in M_K}WC(E/K_{\nu})\textbraceright$$
```

How do I make my brackets larger than the `\prod` within it?

Comment: `\bigl[` or `\biggl[` or `\left[ \right]`

Comment: what if I want to use curly brackets?

Comment: Use `\{` or `\}`.

Comment: Please consider reading [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: To get curly brackets with the correct size, you can (should?) use `\left\{` and `\right\}`.

Comment: @TonioElGringo Can you provide an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\left` and `\right` commands to produce delimiters that will adjust to their content. For instance, to obtain curly brackets, you should use `\left\{` and `\rigth\}` this way:

```
\[\Sh(E/K)=\ker \left\{ WC(E/K)\rightarrow\prod_{\nu\in M_K}WC(E/K_{\nu}) \right\} \]
```

(Notice that I changed `$$` to `\[` and `\]`, [as recommended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to))